# Leitura de uma imagem bitmap

Tags: c

Olá, estou com um trabalho da faculdade sobre esteganografia e um dos requisitos é ler uma imagem no formato bitmap (bmp), porém, já procurei bastante na internet e as informações que existem são as mesmas sobre esse assunto, não sei ao certo o que devo colocar para ler a imagem corretamente, estou precisando de ajuda para compreender. Segue abaixo uma parte do que já foi feito

**OBS: ESSE É O arquivo "lerImagemBMP.h" do código**

```
#ifndef LERIMAGEMBMP__
#define LERIMAGEMBMP__

/*Define o cabeçalho da imagem com o formato BMP*/
typedef struct { 
    char formato[2]; //Especifica o formato da imagem bmp
    int tambytes; //Define o tamanho em Bytes da imagem
    short int reservado1;
    short int reservado2;
    int numbytesdeslocado;

} HEADERARQUIVO;

 /*Estrutura que define as propriedades da imagem BMP*/ 
typedef struct{
    int tamanhoCabecalho; 
    int largura; // Define a largura da imagem
    int altura; // Define a altura da imagem
    short int qualiPlanos;
    short int bitsPixel;
    int compressao;
    int tamanhoImagem;
    int horizontal;
    int vertical;
    int numPaletaCores;
    int numCoresImportantes;

} HEADERIMAGEM;


typedef struct {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char reservado;

} PALETA;


/*Cabeçalho da função que será
responsável por ler a imagem no formato BMP*/
void ler_imagem_bmp(FILE *img_orig, FILE *img_copia_bmp); 

#endif


**OBS: ESSE É O arquivo .c do código**


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lerImagemBMP.h"


void ler_imagem_bmp(FILE *img_orig, FILE *img_copia_bmp){

    char *nomeArquivobmp;
    char *copiaArquivobmp;
    nomeArquivobmp = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    copiaArquivobmp = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    PALETA **Matriz;
    int i, j;


    printf("Informe o nome do arquivo a ser lido:\n");
        scanf("%s", nomeArquivobmp);

    img_orig = fopen(nomeArquivobmp, "rb");


    if(img_orig == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERRO AO TENTAR ABRIR O ARQUIVO %s\n", nomeArquivobmp);
    }


    HEADERARQUIVO cabecalho;
    HEADERIMAGEM imagem;


    fscanf(img_orig, "%s", cabecalho.formato);

    if(strcmp(cabecalho.formato, "BM") != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "O FORMATO DA IMAGEM NÃO É BMP\n");
        fclose(img_orig);
    }

    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &cabecalho.tambytes);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%hu", &cabecalho.reservado1);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%hu", &cabecalho.reservado2);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &cabecalho.numbytesdeslocado);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.tamanhoCabecalho);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.largura);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.altura);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%hu", &imagem.bitsPixel);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.tamanhoImagem);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.horizontal);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.vertical);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.numPaletaCores);
    fscanf(img_orig, "%d", &imagem.numCoresImportantes);



    fprintf(img_copia_bmp, "%s%d%d%d", cabecalho.formato, cabecalho.tambytes, cabecalho.reservado1, cabecalho.reservado2);
    fprintf(img_copia_bmp, "%d%d%d%d%d", cabecalho.numbytesdeslocado, imagem.tamanhoCabecalho, imagem.largura, imagem.altura, imagem.bitsPixel);
    fprintf(img_copia_bmp, "%d%d%d%d%d", imagem.tamanhoImagem, imagem.horizontal, imagem.vertical, imagem.numPaletaCores, imagem.numCoresImportantes);


    Matriz = (PALETA**) malloc(imagem.largura * sizeof(PALETA*));
    for(i=0; i<imagem.largura; i++){

        Matriz[i] = (PALETA*) malloc(imagem.altura * sizeof(PALETA));
        for(j=0; j<imagem.altura; j++){
            fscanf(img_orig, "%c%c%c", &Matriz[i][j].r, &Matriz[i][j].g, &Matriz[i][j].b);
        }
    }


    for(i=imagem.largura; i<=0; i--){
        for(j=0; j<imagem.altura; j++){
            fprintf(img_copia_bmp, "%c%c%c", Matriz[i][j].r, Matriz[i][j].g, Matriz[i][j].b);
        }
    }

    fclose(img_orig);
    fclose(img_copia_bmp);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, você precisa ser mais específico sobre o que exatamente não está entendendo. Dessa forma fica difícil de compreender como te ajudar.
Será difícil alguém postar um tutorial explicando passo a passo como fazer, pois não é o propósito do site. Vou deixar mais uma dica, entretanto é necessário que você comece teu código e aponte onde não está entendendo ou qual sua dificuldade específica. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure

Answer (score 2):

Ok - basicamente, deixe o "fscanf" para lá - ele é uma função auxiliar penada principalmente para ler arquivos cuj conteúdo seja texto,  e nesse caso pode mais atrapalhar do que ajudar. Esta resposta dá umas linhas gerais com o exemplo de como pode começar a ficar o código em C.

Ler e escrever formatos de arquivo já definidos manualmente é uma das coisas mais legais de se fazer em C ou outra linguagem - mas também algo que temos que ter em mente onde é importante não ficar re-inventando a roda.

Em quase todos os projetos "da vida real" quando temos que ler ou escrever uma imagem num formato de arquivos específico, não reimplementamos todo o código para isso: usamos uma biblioteca já pronta, bem definida, que pode tratar a imagem em todos os seus tipos e subtipos - em geral há chamadas nas bibliotecas para as quais você passa um nome de arquivo, e recebe de volta um ponteiro para uma região da memória onde estão todos os dados tipo: largura, altura da imagem, bytes por pixel e para os pixels propriamente ditos.

Dito isso, é claro que é possível ler e escrever arquivos de images sem ter as bibliotecas prontas, mas a dificuldade varia de acordo com o tipo de arquivo: JPEG por exemplo, tem algoritmos de compressão bem complicados e específicos, e re-escreve-los daria um bocado de trabalho. Formatos como .PNG, .PCX e outros são bem mais simples, mas ainda tem algoritmos de compressão envolvidos.  Já o tipo mais comum de arquivos BMP por outro lado nao tem compressão alguma - o que signfica que após extrair os dados do cabeçalho, você tem os dados diretamente da imagem-  isso torna o formato legal para uma primeira abordagem em trabalhos desse tipo (e inviável para o uso comum no dia a dia já que sem compressão alguma esses arquivos podem ter 10 vezes o tamanho de arquivos equivalentes em PNG)

Então - uma das coisas legais é que o cabeçalho de um arquivo .BMP pode ser mapeado quase que diretamente, senão diretamente, para um struct em C. Os vários campos da struct vão ter a largura e altura da imagem, número de cores, etc...  Acredito eu para esse trabalho você vai precisar somente de imagens RGB com 24 bits (3 bytes) por pixel, que são mais fáceis ainda de mexer.

O próximo passo é procurar pela especificação do formato de arquivo (e dentro dessa, filtrar no tipo de arquivo que queremos) - e dos documentos encontrados tentar criar uma struct em C - eu faço a busca por "bmp file spec" - e vamos ver - este link parece bom:
http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm - mesmo por que, no mesmo tom que estou escrevendo essa resposta, ele vai dizendo quais são as variações mais usadas dentre os cabeçalhos e tipos de campo.

ENtão la a primeira coisa que vemos é que os primeiros bytes são um "File header" - e que referenciam logo depois um "image header" dentro desse file.  Ele diz o tamanho de cada campo, entao o negócio é criar em C um struct que tenha campos do mesmo tamanho - você vai ver na especificação:

```
Field Name  Size in Bytes   Description
bfType  2   The characters "BM"
bfSize  4   The size of the file in bytes
bfReserved1 2   Unused - must be zero
bfReserved2 2   Unused - must be zero
bfOffBits   4   Offset to start of Pixel Data
```

Siginificando que os dois primeiros bytes vão ser fixos e são o identificador do arquivo - é um valor de 16 bits que representa o ASCII da letra B no primeiro byte e da letra M no segundo byte.  O seu código de leitura pode checar esse número se ele for diferente disso, encere o programa diznedo que não é  um arquivo BMP.

A partir daí tem outros campos que poderiam ser algo do tipo

```
struct BMPFileHeader {
short unsigned int bfType;
unsigned long int  bfSize;
unsigned short int bfReserved1;
unsigned short int bfReserved2;
unsigned long int brOffbits;

};
```

Perceba que ele já tem um campo que diz onde começam os pixels em si - mas antes dos pixels, vamos ter uma outra struct com os dados do tipo largura e altura - você percebe que vai precisar preencher a próxima também - acredito que dando a dica até aqui  você vai conseguir ler a especificação e ler os outros campos necessários. Para ler essa cabeçalho, você vai precisar de código do tipo

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file
    struct BMPFileHeader header;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if ( !file ){printf("Problema ao abrir o arquivo %s ", argv[1]); exit(1);}
    fread(*file, *header, sizeof(BMPFileHeader);
    if (header.bfType != ('B' << 8 + 'M')) {{printf("O arquivo %s não é um BMP válido", argv[1] ); exit(1);}
    ...
}
```

De forma similar, você descreve a struct para dados na imagem que vem a seguir no link que passei - embora para o uso simplificado, você vá precisar apenas dos campos biWidth, biHeight, e biBitCount - então poderia fazer uma struct simplificada que lê somente os bytes até esse ponto - com "if"s você verifica se o valor de "biBitCount" é 24 - caso contrário, sai com um erro também (imagem != RGB com 8 bits por pixel). E os campos Width e Height vão ter a largura e altura da imagem  nesse ponto, pode fazer um fseek para o valor que está no campo bfOffBits da struct do Header acima - e ler a quantidade de bytes "biWidth * biHeight * 3 " para uma áreade memória alocada com malloc.  Aí estarão seus valores de pixel.

Para regravar o arquivo você pode seguir uma técnica análoga - reutilizando as structs para os cabeçalhos já usadas na leitura (mas nesse caso, você tem que criar a  struct inteira para o Image Header).

Acredito que com isso você consiga começar. Boa sorte.